# CLEAR_TOP and saving extra intent fields

Tags: android

I've got a sequence of A,B,C  activities. From C activity I do:

```
    Intent clearTopIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Class.forName(getIntent().getExtras().getString("prev_activity").toString()));
    clearTopIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(clearTopIntent);
```

which calls activity B with clear_top flag.

My problem is when cleared activity B launches mExtras in mIntent object are empty. What can be done to retain those extra values ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you:

```
intent.putExtras(intentSource)
```

and the `intentSource = getIntent()`

really i didn't get your question correctly.

Comment: ?? Activity B accepts extras but when I want to launch previous activity from top via CLEAR_TOP I essentialy dont have those extras and they are not recovered in OnCreate method